# how to ask an overlay item one the map

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay, overlayitem

I have created an overlayitem list for my activity. But I want add item to the list(for example, I create a button for trigger the event) after I run the application and show the item on the map. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the [MapView tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview), there is an example there.

Comment: I've viewed this tutorial before, the problem for me is that they just add 2 items at the same case, but for me, I would like to add a new item to the overlaylist when I click the button or a certain term triggered.